Best way to go through two pandas dfs and using the data in an external function in python
I have two pandas dfs one contains a list of workers and the other contains a list of tasks. I plan to assign the tasks to the workers. Each task requires a certain number of workers and the way I am doing it right now is by going through the tasks df and stop at each row and go through the workers df and keep assigning workers until the task has enough. Then I move to the next task and so on. I also go through the workers one by one and decide if the worker is assigned or not based on an external function that gives 1 to assign or 0 zero to pass.
I am not sure if the way I am approaching this is right or if I should be doing it in a different way. Let me know if you have a suggestion for a cleaner way to assign each task the required number of workers based on the decision of the external function.
The tasks df looks like this:
task_id day shift   workers_needed
0   1   4   1   3
1   2   4   2   5
2   3   7   1   4
3   4   5   2   4

and the workers df looks like this:
    worker_id   name
0   101 Worker_101
1   102 Worker_102
2   103 Worker_103
3   104 Worker_104

My current method is in the code below:
you can see the while loop goes while i <len(tasks_df) but then I had to add an if statement to stop the loop if i >len(tasks_df)-1. I tried several options changing the condition of the while loop but it either misses the last row by making the first condition -1 or it goes one extra row if I remove the second condition.
    i = 0

cur_task = tasks_df.iloc[i]['task_id']
needed_workers = tasks_df.iloc[i]['workers_needed']
print(f"Current Task is = {cur_task}")
print(f"needed workers = {needed_workers}")

while i < len(tasks_df):
  # print(f" i = {i}")
  random_int = random.randint(0, 1)
  print(f"random_int = {random_int}")
  if(random_int==1):
    needed_workers-= 1
    print(f"updated needed workers = {needed_workers}")
    if needed_workers==0:
      i+=1
      if i>len(tasks_df)-1:
        break
      cur_task = tasks_df.iloc[i]['task_id']
      needed_workers = tasks_df.iloc[i]['workers_needed']
      print(f"Current Task is = {cur_task} ----------------")
      print(f"needed workers = {needed_workers}")

 

I am making the decision to assign for now using a random variable that gives 1 or 0. The decision itself is not important now just the way to go through the dfs and use the decision to assign the needed workers to the tasks.

what would be the expected output? is it in the worker df to add a column with the task assigned to them?

I am planning to create a new df that includes all the assignments and keep the original dfs as they are. I will the use the new df to do some calculations and easily redo the assignments if needed instead of adding a column to an existing df. Each new assignment will be a separate row and this way I can change a single assignment without affecting the others.

You could use iterows() instead in the following way. Iterates directly over the rows of tasks_df using iterrows(), which is clearer and safer than managing loop indices manually. Simulates the decision-making process and assigns workers until the task's requirements are met or there are no more available workers. I base this entirely on the logic I could read from your presented code, so unless it it was wrong this should produce what you want.
import pandas as pd
import random

tasks_data = {
    'task_id': [1, 2, 3, 4],
    'day': [4, 4, 7, 5],
    'shift': [1, 2, 1, 2],
    'workers_needed': [3, 5, 4, 4]
}
workers_data = {
    'worker_id': [101, 102, 103, 104],
    'name': ['Worker_101', 'Worker_102', 'Worker_103', 'Worker_104']
}

tasks_df = pd.DataFrame(tasks_data)
workers_df = pd.DataFrame(workers_data)

available_workers = list(workers_df['worker_id'])

assignments = {task_id: [] for task_id in tasks_df['task_id']}  

for _, task in tasks_df.iterrows():
    print(f"Current Task: {task['task_id']} needs {task['workers_needed']} workers")
    
    while task['workers_needed'] > 0 and available_workers:
        if random.randint(0, 1) == 1:
            assigned_worker = available_workers.pop(0) 
            assignments[task['task_id']].append(assigned_worker)
            task['workers_needed'] -= 1
            print(f"Assigned Worker {assigned_worker}. Remaining: {task['workers_needed']}")

    if task['workers_needed'] > 0:
        print(f"Not enough workers for Task {task['task_id']}. Needed: {task['workers_needed']} more.")

print("Assignments:", assignments)

which returns
Current Task: 1 needs 3 workers
Assigned Worker 101. Remaining: 2
Assigned Worker 102. Remaining: 1
Assigned Worker 103. Remaining: 0
Current Task: 2 needs 5 workers
Assigned Worker 104. Remaining: 4
Not enough workers for Task 2. Needed: 4 more.
Current Task: 3 needs 4 workers
Not enough workers for Task 3. Needed: 4 more.
Current Task: 4 needs 4 workers
Not enough workers for Task 4. Needed: 4 more.
Assignments: {1: [101, 102, 103], 2: [104], 3: [], 4: []}


@Ayham Glad it helped. Mark the answer as accepted so it disappears from the list of unanswered questions. Happy coding!
